# Delayed flow of information in notifications

Tags: bug

Two days ago I cleared the review queue like I am used to. There were two (suggested edit and close vote) reviews which will give you an orange notification in the top bar. But still it said **5 instead of 2** and after reviewing there were 3 left (see picture). This number also appeared yesterday, today it's gone.

Is this a SX issue or do I have hardware/software problems? I am asking this because some days ago (I already chatted about this with @J.Musser) I had a similar bug where I had 2 upvotes on a question but it said that the question was **viewed 1 time**. Even after refreshing the browser (Mozilla Firefox) several times this was the case for some minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That orange notification shows *everyone* the same number, which is the total amount of reviews. That's why when *you* reviewed, the numbers didn't match up. If you are the final reviewer on a certain item, the total number will drop by one. The notification does not show when there are less than 2 total reviews.

Also see [**Notification for reviews shows way too much**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much)

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238698/154443

Answer (score 2):

There is a [meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238698/154443) on this that explains it. Basically any time you have hit skip on a review item, that item still counts but you do not see it.

If you go into your full review items you can see which ones you have skipped.

Comment: Thx. But I can't find the skipped reviews under activity/reviews. Or where should I search?

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are heavily cached. It's likely there were more reviews before you saw them, the number just doesn't get updated constantly.

Comment: So everyone should be seeing those false numbers I guess. Still weird that they have been displayed for more than a day.